# JSON schema validation for base64 string is not working

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am using following schema to validate image base64 string:

```
 {
   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
     "image": {
       "type": "string",
       "media": {
         "contentEncoding": "base64",
         "oneOf": [
               { "mediaType": "image/png" },
               { "mediaType": "image/jpg" },
               { "mediaType": "image/jpeg" }
         ]
       }
     }
   },
   "required": [
     "image"
   ]
 }
```

But the schema is not working, any string, even invalid, is passed to application

I am using [JSON Schema for PHP](https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema) to validate json input

UPDATE

This what I tried to change, but it doesn't work

```
{
 "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
 "type": "object",
 "properties": {
   "image": {
     "title": "image",
     "type": "string",
     "media": {
       "binaryEncoding": "base64",
       "type": "image/png"
     }
   }
 },
 "required": [
   "image"
 ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is old syntax which is no longer supported in JSON Hyper-Schema Draft #4. It changed *contentEncoding* into **binaryEncoding** (see the change log [here](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-hypermedia.html#anchor43)).

A relevant excerpt from the spec follows:

```
    "imgData": {
        "title": "Article Illustration (small)",
        "type": "string",
        "media": {
            "binaryEncoding": "base64",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    }
```

Also, you mentioned nothing about which validator you're using. It may prove important, as compliance across different implementations may vary.

Update: Also, the `$schema` should be `http://json-schema.org/draftv4/hyper-schema` for hyper-schema processing.

Comment: I am using this [validator](https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema). I tried your code, it didn't work neither

Comment: @blahblah, have a look at [this thread](https://github.com/daveclayton/json-schema-validator/issues/87). First, you should modify your $schema (as per my update). What I would suggest also, if your PHP implementation still doesn't work, try to validate with [this](http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/) - they say hyper-schema now works out of the box. I haven't tried for your particular scenario, shouldn't be a big deal to do it as you are already setup with both schema and sample.